# Is there any software to aid in MYSQL optimization?

Tags: mysql, optimization, automation, query-optimization

I have a number of very long and fairly complex stored procedures in my local MYSQL database. I query the database through these stored procedures repeatedly at a high rate all day long.

Time is very much of the essence to me. A millisecond decrease in query time amounts to hours saved because my routines are iterative.

Since my database is so involved, it is difficult for me to optimize everything manually with a "change it and see" approach.

Are there any programs (for Windows 7) that might help me find the bottlenecks? I need both index-related optimization and server variable optimization.

Comment: Yes, it's called DB2 :-) Boom, boom, thanks for listening, I'm here all week :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Almost funny. Any fool knows the punchline is PostgreSQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Query Profiler](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/query-profiler.html) tool in dbForge Studio. It can help you to optimize queries.

Comment: Wow this program is great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL includes its own methods for debugging queries and query plans, the chief among these is the [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) command.  For me, 90% of MySQL optimisation involves using this to some extent.  It takes the trial-and-error out of optimisation because it actually shows you what MySQL is actually doing to solve your query.

You can use any MySQL client (even the command-line MySQL client, which I use a bit) to run `EXPLAIN` queries.  [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is a popular MySQL client which is accessed over the web and tries to make this sort of thing easy, including an easy "EXPLAIN" link for any query you run.

I haven't used Windows-based MySQL clients before but there are a [good selection of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185/what-is-the-best-mysql-client-application-for-windows) to be chosen from.